# Why is $G*M_{sun}=4\pi^2$ when using AU/year units?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astronomy, units, celestial-mechanics

So, when using AU/year units, it turns out that 3rd Kepler Law: $\frac{r^3}{T^2}=\frac{G*M_{sun}}{4\pi^2}=1$, meaning $G*M_{sun}=4\pi^2$, any easy explanation for this? Cheers.

Comment: Do you understand what the values of $r$ and $T$ for Earth are in those units?

Comment: Coincidence. $M_{sun} = \frac{4\pi^2}{G}$. Is this the Sun's mass in Kg? Then the equality won't hold if you use pounds. What about another star, say Betelgeuse? It has a different mass, so the equality doesn't hold for it. But you could make up units where it does hold.

Comment: @mmesser314 It's not a coincidence, given how the chosen units are defined. This is a question about an exact proportionality constant in Kepler's third law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kepler's third law
$$\frac{r^3}{T^2}=\frac{G M_\text{sun}}{4\pi^2}$$
is valid for all planets of the sun.
So we can choose the earth which has $r=1$ AU and $T=1$ year.
Inserting these we get
$$\frac{(1\text{ AU})^3}{(1\text{ year})^2}=\frac{G M_\text{sun}}{4\pi^2}$$
or
$$G M_\text{sun}={4\pi^2}\frac{\text{AU}^3}{\text{year}^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

In SI units, an equation for the year ($T$) in terms of the distance to the sun ($r$) and the mass of the sun ($M_s$) comes from setting the force due to gravity equal to the centripetal acceleration needed to maintain the Earth's circular orbit:
$$
G\frac{M_sM_e}{r^2}=M_er\left(\frac{2\pi}{T}\right)^2
$$
So we solve for $GM_s$ and we get:
$$
GM_s=r^3\left(\frac{2\pi}{T}\right)^2=\frac{4\pi^2r^3}{T^2}
$$
So if I'm using units where $r=\text{distance to earth}=1$ and $T=1\text{ year}=1$ then we get:
$$
GM_s=4\pi^2
$$
This line of reasoning is also how we derive Kepler's third law in the first place. Except if I remember correctly, Kepler's third law is in terms of the semimajor axis, and it still holds true if the orbit isn't circular.

Comment: The general case $T^2=\frac{4\pi^2a^3}{GM}$ follows from $b^2=a\ell,\,h^2=GM\ell,\,T=\frac{2\pi ab}{h}$. Here $h$ is the specific angular momentum, $a$ and $b$ are the major and minor semi-axes, and $\ell$ is the semi-latus rectum, so my first equation follows from $b=a\sqrt{1-e^2},\,\ell=a(1-e^2)$.